# How /etc/hosts effect the time cost of springboot project start on Idea Mac version?

Tags: macos, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I'm using intellij idea 2019 on macbook, and found that my springboot project started quite slow.

Someone told me to add the machineName to the 127.0.0.1 record in the hosts file, and it really works.

Can someone explain how this works?

Comment: Another good read that offers more information on the matter is this comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7087#issuecomment-251607070

Answer (score 0):

Adding records to hosts file helps to avoid DNS resolve issue: https://thoeni.io/post/macos-sierra-java/